# Qt How to properly connect to a phone programmatically (Bluetooth A2DP, AVRCP, HSP, HFP) in Linux

Tags: qt, bluetooth, bluez, pulseaudio, a2dp

I am trying to develop an application that uses bluez stack along with pulseaudio and ofono in order to connect to a phone and achieve tasks such as media playback (A2DP), media control (AVRCP), and handsfree-based telephony (HFP). When I connect to my phone through `bluetoothctl`, it automatically connects to all the available profiles, so using all profiles A2DP, AVRCP, HFP through my program is achievable. If I don't connect to my phone using `bluetoothctl`, handsfree /HFP modem is not enabled/powered in ofono.

However, when I use QBluetoothSocket in Qt and connect using a profile, there is always a profile that is not connected. For example connecting to Handsfree profile, telephony works, but the media control does not work. In short, I want to be able to connect to bluetooth as `bluetoothctl` does. What I have in Qt is as follows (in short):

```
static const QList<QBluetoothUuid> audioUuids = QList<QBluetoothUuid>()
        << QBluetoothUuid::HeadsetAG
        << QBluetoothUuid::AV_RemoteControlTarget;
..
void BtConnection::setConnection(int index)
{
    if(m_bluetoothSocket == nullptr) {
        m_bluetoothSocket = new QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol);
        qDebug() << "Created Bluetooth Socket";
    }
    if(m_bluetoothSocket != nullptr) {
        connect(m_bluetoothSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
        connect(m_bluetoothSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
        connect(m_bluetoothSocket, SIGNAL(error(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError)),
                this, SLOT(connectionError(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError)));
    }

    m_device = get(index);

    // Check if an element in m_device.serviceUuids() match with an element in audioUuids
    QList<QBluetoothUuid>::const_iterator uuid;
    for (uuid = audioUuids.begin(); uuid != audioUuids.end(); ++uuid) {
        if(m_device.serviceUuids().indexOf(*uuid) > 0) {
            // This device supports one of the uuids we have scanned for
            if(m_bluetoothSocket != nullptr) {
                qDebug() << "*****Connecting...   " << *uuid;
                m_bluetoothSocket->connectToService(m_device.address(), *uuid);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    qDebug() << "*****Cannot connect to service...";
}
```

I would be willing to post more of the code if this is not clear to you. Any help is greately appreciated on how to connect to bluetooth with Qt as `bluetoothctl` does.

Comment: I have the same problem,  You solved? How did you do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer but you might want to check KDE's [KDEConnect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) project. It already does what you are looking for and might either be a source of inspiration or you could contribute to the project.

Comment: KDEConnect is the greatest thing since sliced bread, but it doesn't do what the author wants to write, namely HFP.